# Pass an array as template type

Tags: c++, templates

I need to pass an array as a template type. How can achieve it. For example, I want something like this.

```
Fifo<array, Q_SIZE> f; // This is a queue of arrays (to avoid false sharing)
```

What should I put in place of *array*? Assume I need an array of *int*. Also note that I don't want `std::vector` or a pointer to an array. I want the whole basic array, something equivalent of say *int array[32]*.

Comment: If you're using C++ 11 `std::array<Q_SIZE>` should do the trick

Comment: @user1018562 Can you typedef your array before? I mean `typedef int myArrayType[16]` and then pass myArrayType.

Comment: if you are using boost `boost::array<int,Q_SIZE>`

Comment: I don't want to use any std::_ or boost::_.

Comment: @user1018562 If you really prefer doing stuff the hard way just do `Foo<int[10], Q_SIZE>`

Comment: I tried to typedef an array type: typedef int myArrayType[16]. also failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Fifo<int[32], Q_SIZE> f;
```

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T, int N>
struct Fifo {
  T t;
};

int main () {
 const int Q_SIZE  = 32;
 Fifo<int[32],Q_SIZE> f;
 std::cout << sizeof f << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass *array type* when creating queue you can write

```
template <typename Array>
struct Fifo;

template <typename T, int size>
struct Fifo<T[size]>
{

};
```

or just

```
template <typename Array>
struct Fifo
{
};
```

and use it like

```
int main()
{
    Fifo<int[10]> fa;

}
```

Then, you should understand, that `int[10]` is completely different type from `int[11]`, and once you created  `Fifo<int[10]>` you cannot store here arrays of size 11 or 9 anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Well I've found a solution. I can wrap the array in a structure, such as below.

```
typedef struct
{
 int array[32];
} my_array;
```

Then I can use it as follows.

```
Fifo<my_array, Q_SIZE> f;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `std::end` function in C++ 11 has an overload for array types that nicely demonstrate this.
Here's a possible implementation of it:

```
template< class T, std::size_t N >
T* end(T(&array)[N]) {
    return array + N;
}
```

If you need an object that wraps an array, a templated factory function will help creating it:

```
template< class T, std::size_t N >
struct fifo {
    T(&array)[N];
};

template< class T, std::size_t N >
fifo<T,N> make_fifo(T(&array)[N]) {
    return Fifo<T,N>{ array };
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

    // Create object from array using template argument deduction
    auto fifo = make_fifo(arr);
}
```